# Can a Mongo Stitch app be renamed in the web UI?

Tags: mongodb-stitch

I am trying Mongo Stitch to see if I can use it for some small web apps.

I created a simple application to play with some incoming web hooks and triggers, and called it `MyApp`. I am now expanding the application, and I have a purpose for it, so I'd like to give it a more meaningful name. However, on the **Stitch Applications** page, the only feature available in the app context menus is "Delete".

I expect I could do an export and an import using the console command, and editing the text files in-between, and if there is no other option, that is what I will do. However, it seems such an obvious oversight, I wonder if I have just not seen a menu option somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you cannot change it. Exporting it, changing the app name (and removing the clientAppId), and importing again should work. Essentially creating a new app.

Comment: Thanks Haley - that's what I did in the end. It seemed rather destructive though - an endpoint within the app no longer works, and I suspect it has changed its ID or something. It's only for playing around at the moment, but I wonder whether the system is ready for production.

Comment: There does not seem to be much provision for taking an app through staging/nonprod to production, except perhaps by importing a repo and using a device to change the JSON declaration file in the root. I might ask another question about that...

Comment: Yea, that's super annoying! If you have suggestions, add them to this canny board: https://mongodb.canny.io/mongodb-stitch.

Comment: Thanks, I might just do that! I notice you've answered a lot of questions on this topic, despite there not being much support material available on the web  outside of Mongo's own site. Have you built production apps with it yourself? Or are you on the Stitch dev team? `:-)`

Comment: I’m an engineer on Stitch :)

Comment: Ooh, nice project to work on! I will see if I can get some suggestions onto your ideas board.

Comment: Follow-up post: https://mongodb.canny.io/mongodb-stitch/p/allow-stitch-apps-to-be-renamed

Comment: Update for readers: I have received an email to say that as a result of the rebrand/shift for Stitch, the feedback forum will be shut down, and only some of the feedback will be copied over to existing MongoDB tickets. Mine did not make the cut, and I am a bit hesitant to raise it again, given that I should not need to. I am rather out of the loop for Stitch - maybe it has now been implemented, or maybe someone will re-raise the feature suggestion in the future.

Comment: Hi Haley - I recently reminded myself of Mongo Stitch, and did a quick search for it, only to find that it appears to have been erased from the company website. Does the product exist in any fashion within MongoDB Atlas now, or was it discontinued?