# Are dependencies included in the import/export in MongoDB Stitch?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-stitch

I tried MongoDB Stitch earlier this year, and at the time it did not feel like a finished product (for example, [apps cannot be renamed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54542489/472495)). I am giving it another go, and this time I am interested to see how I could create automated tests for my Stitch functions using Jest ([this also may not be straightforward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59228616/how-to-get-jest-to-see-the-functions-i-am-writing-for-mongodb-stitch)).

I have noticed that the Functions section has a *Dependencies<sup>Beta</sup>* tab. Here one may zip up NPM modules in a tarball, and they will become available in the Stitch JS environment. I wonder if I could use this to circumvent the import difficulties I am experiencing with the functions system - instead I could make (untested) lightweight calls from Functions to Dependencies, and then just test the dependencies.

However, I want to be able to import my app automatically using the console command, to deploy automatically in a CI pipeline. For this to work, import/export would need to include dependencies as well, but [the file-format docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/deploy/application-schema/) do not mention dependencies. Is there any support for syncing dependencies from the console, as part of an app import?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any support for syncing dependencies from the console, as part of an app import?

Yes, you can import dependencies using [mongodb-stitch-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-stitch-cli) (v1.10+).

To upload external dependencies:

- First need a local `node_modules` folder containing at least one `Node.js` package. If the `node_modules` folder does not already exist, `npm install <package>` will automatically creates it.
- Next you need to package them up in an archive so you can upload them to Stitch:

  ```
  tar -czf node_modules.tgz node_modules/
  ```

  Other supported formats/extensions are : `.zip`, `.tar`, `.gz`, `.tgz`
- Next you can place the archive into [the functions directory in the application file schema](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/deploy/application-schema/#functions). i.e.

  ```
  ├── functions/
  │   └── <function name>/
  │       ├── config.json
  │       └── source.js
  │   └── node_modules.tgz
  ```
- Execute the import command with `--include-dependencies`, i.e:

  ```
  stitch-cli import --app-id <APP_ID> --path ./your_app --include-dependencies

  Creating draft for app...
  Draft created successfully...
  Importing app...
  Deploying app...
  Deploying app...
  Done.
  Importing hosting assets...
  Done.
  ```

Please note that currently `stitch-cli` does not support export for dependencies yet.

See also [Stitch: Upload External Dependencies](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/functions/upload-external-dependencies/) to upload from the UI.

Comment: That's great, thanks Wan! Apologies, I did not spot it was in the docs - or perhaps that is a new addition?

Comment: It is interesting that zip files can be no larger than 10M - I have seen Node dependency trees much larger than that, but I assume they compress well.

Comment: Incidentally, since you work for Mongo, you may be interested in my [Dockerised Stitch Console](https://github.com/halfer/docker-stitch-cli) - it's a way to containerise the console utility for people who don't want to run it on their host directly.

Comment: Hi @halfer, it's not entirely in docs yet. The documentation that I posted is mostly for the UI import but may add some information. Yes, it should compress well. Thanks I've starred your GitHub project for future reference.